# In which cases should we use java.class.path of ANT over CLASSPATH of my OS (set at .bashrc, say)?

Tags: ant, classpath

I just found the build-in classpath property of ant, namely, java.class.path, is different from my CLASSPATH that I set in .bashrc.

Would you like to tell me how ANT sets its java.class.path? In which case should we use it over CLASSPATH?

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANT has its own `CLASSPATH`property , you want to use it if you want to build your project using `ANT`

like this

`<property name="classpath" value="${lib}/antlr-2.7.6.jar;${lib}/calculate.jar;${lib}/cglib-2.2.jar;${lib}/commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar;${lib}/commons-collections-3.1.jar;${lib}/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;${lib}/commons-digester-1.7.jar;${lib}/commons-logging-1.1.jar;${lib}/dom4j-1.6.1.jar;${lib}/groovy-all-1.5.5.jar;${lib}/hibernate3.jar;${lib}/iText-2.1.7.jar;${lib}/iTextAsian.jar;${lib}/jasper_chart1.1.0.jar;${lib}/jasperreports-3.7.2.jar;${lib}/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar;${lib}/jta-1.1.jar;${lib}/log4j.jar;${lib}/mySecurityPackage.jar;${lib}/poi-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar;${lib}/ReportsEngine.jar;${lib}/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar;${lib}/slf4j-log4j12.jar;${lib}/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar" />`

else use your `OS CLASSPATH` when you build your project using `COMMAND LINE`